# Problem using Jupyter on VSCode: Data Science library ipykernel is not installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I try to use Jupyter on VSCode

I have created en virtualenv and install jupyterlab and pandas
but when I run a .ipynb files I got an information message:

> Data Science library ipykernel is not installed. Install?

I click Yes to install but even if in terminal it seems to be succefully installed

> Successfully installed backcall-0.2.0 colorama-0.4.3 decorator-4.4.2 ipykernel-5.3.4 ipython-7.17.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jedi-0.17.2 jupyter-client-6.1.6 jupyter-core-4.6.3 parso-0.7.1 pickleshare-0.7.5 prompt-toolkit-3.0.6 pygments-2.6.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pywin32-228 pyzmq-19.0.2 tornado-6.0.4 traitlets-4.3.3 wcwidth-0.2.5

I have an error message from VSCode:

> IPyKernel not installed into interpreter Python 3.7.4 32-bit

Comment: Problem comes from python version use in VSCode

Comment: Is the python version you are currently using in VSCode python2 or python3? If it is python2, please try to switch the python version to python3.